# What does Java Node normalize method do?

Tags: java, xml, normalization

I'm doing some tests, but I see no difference when I use or not the `normalize()` method.
But the examples at ExampleDepot website use it.
So, what is it for? (The documentation wasn't clear for me either)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can programmatically build a DOM tree that has extraneous structure not corresponding to actual XML structures - specifically things like multiple nodes of type text next to each other, or empty nodes of type text. The `normalize()` method removes these, i.e. it combines adjacent text nodes and removes empty ones.

This can be useful when you have other code that expects DOM trees to always look like something built from an actual XML document.

This basically means that the following XML element

```
<foo>hello 
wor
ld</foo>
```

could be represented like this in a denormalized node:

```
Element foo
    Text node: ""
    Text node: "Hello "
    Text node: "wor"
    Text node: "ld"
```

When normalized, the node will look like this

```
Element foo
    Text node: "Hello world"
```

Answer (score 4):

It cleans code from adjacent Text nodes and empty Text nodes

Answer (score 2):

there are a lot of possible DOM trees that correspond to the same XML structure and each XML structure has at least one corresponding DOM tree. So conversion from DOM to XML is [surjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function).
So it may happen that:

```
dom_tree_1 != dom_tree_2
# but:
dom_tree_1.save_DOM_as_XML() == dom_tree_2.save_DOM_as_XML()
```

And there is no way for ensuring:

```
dom_tree == dom_tree.save_DOM_as_XML().load_DOM_from_XML()
```

But we would like to have it [bijective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection). That means each XML structure corresponds to one particular DOM tree.

So you can define a subset of all possible DOM trees that is bijective to the set of all possible XML structures.

```
# still:
dom_tree.save_DOM_as_XML() == dom_tree.normalized().save_DOM_as_XML()
# but with:
dom_tree_n = dom_tree.normalize() 
# we now even have:
dom_tree_n == dom_tree_n.save_DOM_as_XML().load_DOM_from_XML().normalize()
```

So normalized DOM trees can be perfectly reconstructed from their XML representation. There is no information loss.

Answer (score 0):

Normalize the root element of the XML document.  This ensures that all Text nodes under the root node are put into a "normal" form, which means that  there are neither adjacent Text nodes nor empty Text nodes in the document.