# What is xml normalization?

Tags: java, xml, terminology, normalization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does Java Node normalize method do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457955/what-does-java-node-normalize-method-do)

What is xml normalization .I found following in javadoc but i cant understand it?Can anyone help?

```
public void normalize()
```

Puts all Text nodes in the full depth of the sub-tree underneath this Node, including attribute nodes, into a "normal" form where only structure (e.g., elements, comments, processing instructions, CDATA sections, and entity references) separates Text nodes, i.e., there are neither adjacent Text nodes nor empty Text nodes. This can be used to ensure that the DOM view of a document is the same as if it were saved and re-loaded, and is useful when operations (such as XPointer [XPointer] lookups) that depend on a particular document tree structure are to be used. If the parameter "normalize-characters" of the DOMConfiguration object attached to the Node.ownerDocument is true, this method will also fully normalize the characters of the Text nodes.
    Note: In cases where the document contains CDATASections, the normalize operation alone may not be sufficient, since XPointers do not differentiate between Text nodes and CDATASection nodes.
    Since:
    DOM Level 3

Comment: It would be helpful to provide a link to that javadoc :)

Answer (score 4):

Parsers will often return "surprising" text nodes, where text is split up into multiple nodes, or, less commonly, empty text nodes.  This is a side-effect of them being streamlined for maximum performance.  It may happen when there's ignorable whitespace, buffer boundaries, or anywhere else that it was just convenient for the parser.

`normalize()` will get rid of all these surprises, merging adjacent text nodes and removing empty ones.

Comment: can you show us an example ? ie an xml doc which will throw "surprises" for sure when we parse it without normalize() ? Once we can compare with normalize and without it, we can see the difference and everything will be much clearer.

Comment: @AppleGrinder - I can't reliably point at any particular example - it depends on what parser you are using.  I think it's probably safe to say, however, that if the text of an element is, say, a megabyte long, that you'll get multiple text nodes due to splitting at buffer boundaries.  The most unpredictable kind of node-splitting is when it's done on buffer boundaries, because it's seldom and appears to happen "randomly", so tests may pass.  I know I've seen Apache Xerces (and therefore probably the default Java parser) do this.

Comment: I would expect multiple text nodes after something has manipulated the DOM, not from a parser. Is there documentation or an example of this happening? If you modify the tree by appending text nodes to places but have an algorithm which assumes each element has no more than 1 text node which you want to run after those modifications, that would be the time to use normalize.

Comment: @binki A lot of water has gone over the dam since I wrote, things may have changed.  I don't do Java anymore.  If you want to test a particular parser, I'd suggest parsing at least, say, a megabyte of text in a single node.  Let the parser read the file from disk - don't feed it the whole file in memory.  The idea is to ensure that the parser encounters a read-buffer boundary in the middle of a node.  If it doesn't split it, it probably normalizes for you.

Comment: @binki Without some assurance from docs, I'd make no assumptions, however.

Answer (score -1):

The API doc explains it in great details, not sure what there is to explain. Basically the method converts the DOM subtree beginning at `this` node into a "standard format" by combining adjacent text nodes, eliminating empty text nodes and optionally also normalizes characters that are Unicode composites.

Comment: I guess that the OP is asking for a plain english example, with minimum jargon perhaps. Okay, think of it this way - how would you explain it to a lay person ? Please also see my comment to Ed Staub's answer.